# Why .png and other types of images aren't loading on my browser?

Tags: windows, image, png, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-chromium

I'm facing a very technical issue which is very frustrating, the images in the websites are not loading, instead of image I can only see a square pattern, I'm giving some of the screenshots below.
[image: Problem sample]
[image: Problem sample 2]

I will be very happy if anyone can give the solution of the problem, and this error occurs almost every website I visit.

About my browser - Microsoft Edge - 112.0.1722.34 (Official build) (64-bit)

- I tried many types of tips and tricks like clearing cache, restarting laptop, clear data of the browser etc.... but still they aren't working

Comment: Does the issue also occur in other browsers like Chrome, Firefox and so on? Do you have any extensions installed in the browser? Have you enabled show all images in *edge://settings/content/images* in Edge?

Comment: Yes, it was happening in chrome browser too, that's why I uninstalled it but I never tried firefox. I have only one extension on my browser that is quill bot ( corrects the grammar and enhance the sentence.), Yes I have switched to strict mode to balanced mode but still same, no changes.

Comment: Have you checked if images are enabled in *edge://settings/content/images*? Besides, also check *edge://settings/content/javascript* to see if JavaScript is enabled. If it happens in all browsers, it seems more related with your computer not browsers. You can also try to clear "Temporary Internet Files" in "Disk Cleanup" app.

Comment: Here I'm sharing screenshot for it, where everything is enabled on my system [![Image-for-image.png](https://i.postimg.cc/vHPsqrhF/Image-for-image.png)](https://postimg.cc/jLJmCJBZ) , [![for-javascript.png](https://i.postimg.cc/65VcLKry/for-javascript.png)](https://postimg.cc/mtD7B06s)

Comment: The settings look OK. Have you tried clear "Temporary Internet Files" in "Disk Cleanup" app? You can also check if you have any firewall which might have settings prevent image loading. Which version of OS do you use and when does the issue occur? Can you view images in other apps in your computer?

Comment: yes, I tried to "Temporary Internet files" and other methods like clearing cookies etc., and disk cleanup too, but nothing work properly, I use windows 11 :) and this issue occurs when there is an .png image on the website and mostly happens in GitHub. Yes I can see other images in my system properly and magnificently,

Comment: To narrow down the issue, you can have another test: If you use another device and connect to the same network to view the same websites in browsers, can you see the broken images?

Comment: Yesterday, I installed firefox and chrome in my laptop to check weather it is happening in edge or what, then the same thing was happening with me, I mean I installed those browser completely new, and found the same thing but in my friend's laptop everything is working fine.  Here's the link, checkout and tell me weather it is working on your system or not - https://github.com/StarKnightt/marcizhu (just scroll down and you will see a chess board).

Comment: It works fine on my computer. I think it's your computer's issue or your network issue. To identify if it's a network issue, you can connect another device to the same network as your computer's to check if you can see the images. If it's not network issue, you can scan your computer to check if there's any malware or virus.

Comment: I think you are correct, and it is a network issue because same thing is happening with my smartphone too, currently I'm a 5G user and my data speed is almost 300mbps to 400mbps but I think there is some issue with my devices that's why it is  happening, Btw, Thank you for you help and assistance. I'm glad that you helped me.

Answer (score 0):

all website you cant see the picture or only this web you cant see picture?

it is look like the image url is not allow you get, can you use edge browser F12 to see the network?

[image: F12 picture]

Comment: In almost every website I cannot see any picture, I was using brave browser too, I thought that brave has so many blocking techniques that's why I switched to edge but the same thing is happening here. Even in stackoverflow I'm unable to see many images https://imghost.net/oyxthkWzF9orMFd here is an example of it

Comment: As you said I tried f12 and it looks like this https://imghost.net/HmTajLBjHLT1Ypw

Comment: [![Edge-issue.png](https://i.postimg.cc/Twqtbw1h/Edge-issue.png)](https://postimg.cc/5Yy5dfwM) now see it